# Li hover bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, html-lists

I tried to make the hover color of the dropdown menu blue but nothing worked. I tried different codes with no succes. Hope someone can help. My code is below. I'd want the dropdown tabs blue when your mouse hovers it.

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Pudding</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./forums.php">Forums</a></li>

      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <?php if ($user->is_logged_in()) {echo "Welcome";} if (!$user->is_logged_in()) {echo "Please log in";} ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="/?1" name="link1">
              <?php 
                  if($user->is_logged_in()){echo "Log out";}
                  if(!$user->is_logged_in()) {echo "Log in";}
              ?>
              </a></li>
        </ul>
       </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
</div>`
```

Comment: #elementid li a:hover{} should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what worked for me...

First give your very first parent div:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

an id of say #my_blue_nav  then add this CSS.

```
#my_blue_nav li > a:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}

#my_blue_nav li.active a{
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Also make sure your custom.css is loaded after your bootstrap.css

Comment: meadowlandmc.com That's my website. I've pasted your code but it doesnt work.

Comment: @MeesMaas if you copied that CSS exactly it will not work as in your HTML you added "my_blue_nav" as a Class not an ID. SO either change your HTML to id="my_blue_nav" or in your CSS change all of the #my_blue_nav to .my_blue_nav    let me know if that works

Comment: This is my css
.warning {
    color: RED
}
my_blue_nav li > a:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}

my_blue_nav li.active a{
    background-color: blue !important;
} 

dropdown li a:hover{
    color: #013adf
} 
And my HTML:
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right my_blue_nav">
             <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>

but it doesnt work

Comment: @MeesMaas did you copy and paste that exactly?? You are STILL missing the . on my_blue_nav  it should be " .my_blue_nav " do you not even under stand classes and ID's? You should not be asking these question if you dont have a basic understanding of CSS. Dont ask again in till you go on YouTube look up LevelUp Tuts CSS. It is extremely easy to follow and will only take a few hours.